# Access WCF Service endpoint internal state (object properties and methods)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a service with internal state that I need to capture in order to manipulate it. I have several endpoints in my ServiceHost which listen to request from the client. The service object has an observable property for which OnNext is called on one of the contract' methods. Now I would like to Subscribe to the endpoint's observable instace.

I have the idea of adding IEndpointBehavior to each ServiceEndpoint that, on dispatch, calls an observable keyed by the ServiceEndpoint; so in this case I would have a mapping endpoints-observables, but I am not sure how to access the parameters of the call and also I am in the hope that there is an easier way to achieve this.

Any ideas?